# How to print the values at each level in a nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a nested array containing numbers on multiple levels. The array key “number” will be holding an integer corresponding to that level and the key 'sub_level' will be holding an array with the same structure. Each level may or may not have a sub_level.

```
Sample Input

[
    0 => [
            'number' => 72,
            'sub_level' => [
                    'number' => 53,
                    'sub_level' => [
                            'number' => 49
                        ]
              ]
        ],
    1 => [
            'number' => 92,
            'sub_level' => [
                    'number' => 74
                ]
        ],
    2 => [
            'number' => 7
        ]
];
```

```
Sample o/p: 
Level 0: 72,92,7
Level 1: 53,74
Level 2: 49-->
```

Comment: You'd write a recursive function I guess.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this type of problem recursive is great.I have pushed the same levels in the **$higher** variable and the lower levels in the **$lower** variable. Then called the **$lower** var recursively.

```
function print_levels($array, $level = 0 ) {
    foreach ($array as $key1 => $value1) {
        foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2 ) {
            if( is_array( $value2 ) ){
                $lower [] = $value2;
            }else{
                $higher [] = $value2;
            }
        }
    }
    echo 'level '.$level. ': '.  implode( ',', $higher ) . '<br>';
    if( ! isset($lower) )
        return;
    else
        print_levels($lower, ++$level);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easily solved with a recursive function, using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get the `number` values at each level, and again to pass the `sub_level` to the recursive call:

```
function print_numbers($array, $level = 0) {
    if (empty($array)) return;
    echo "level $level: " . implode(',', array_column($array, 'number')) . "\n";
    print_numbers(array_column($array, 'sub_level'), $level+1);
}

print_numbers($input);
```

Output:

```
level 0: 72,92,7
level 1: 53,74
level 2: 49
```

If you want to extract all the numbers into a multi-dimensional array indexed by the level, you can modify the above function to return the values rather than echo them:

```
function save_numbers($array) {
    if (empty($array)) return array();
    return array_merge(array(array_column($array, 'number')), save_numbers(array_column($array, 'sub_level')));;
}

$out = save_numbers($input);
print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 72
            [1] => 92
            [2] => 7
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 53
            [1] => 74
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 49
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/7bevU)

Answer (score 0):

A solution with iterators that deliver the result as a multi-dimensional array. The implode function can be used to generate a list of the form 72,92,7.

```
$level = [];
$it =  new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
foreach($it as $key => $element) {
  if($key == 'number'){
    $level[$it->getDepth()][] = $element;
  }
}
```

Result $level:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 72,
    1 => 92,
    2 => 7,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 53,
    1 => 74,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 49,
  ),
)
```